# How to convert a do while loop to a while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

**How do I convert my do-while loop to a while loop?**

```
int numAttempts = 0;

do
{
    System.out.println("Do you want to convert to Peso or Yen?");
    pesoOrYen = readKeyboard.nextLine();

    if(pesoOrYen.equalsIgnoreCase("Peso")||pesoOrYen.equalsIgnoreCase("Yen"))
    {
        notPesoOrYen = false;
    }
    else if (numAttempts < 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, but '"+pesoOrYen+"' is not a valid currency type. Try again:");
        notPesoOrYen = true; 
    }

    numAttempts++;

} while(notPesoOrYen==true && numAttempts < 3);
```

I tried to do `while(notPesoOrYen==true && numAttempts < 3)` then the statement but it did not work.

**MY FULL CODE**

package currencyconverter;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class CurrencyConverter 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner readKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double doubleUsersCaptial;
    boolean notPesoOrYen=true;
    String pesoOrYen;
    double usersConvertedCapital;
    boolean userInputToRunProgramAgain=true;

    final double US_DOLLAR_TO_PESO = 13.14;
    final double US_DOLLAR_TO_YEN  = 106.02;


    do
    {

        System.out.println    ("How much money in US dollars do you have?");
        String usersCaptial    = readKeyboard.nextLine();
        doubleUsersCaptial = Double.parseDouble(usersCaptial);

        int numAttempts = 0;

        do
        {
            System.out.println    ("Do you want to convert to Peso or Yen?");
            pesoOrYen      = readKeyboard.nextLine();



            if(pesoOrYen.equalsIgnoreCase("Peso")||pesoOrYen.equalsIgnoreCase("Yen"))
            {
                notPesoOrYen = false;
            }
            else if (numAttempts < 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, but '"+pesoOrYen+"' is not a valid currency type. Try again:");
                notPesoOrYen = true; 

            }
        numAttempts++;
        }while(notPesoOrYen==true && numAttempts < 3);

        if(numAttempts==3)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, but '"+pesoOrYen+"' is not a valid currency type.");
            System.out.println("You entered the wrong currency type too many times\nGood Bye");
            System.exit(0); 
        }

        if (pesoOrYen.equalsIgnoreCase("Peso"))
        {
            usersConvertedCapital = doubleUsersCaptial*US_DOLLAR_TO_PESO;
        }
        else 
        {
            usersConvertedCapital = doubleUsersCaptial*US_DOLLAR_TO_YEN;
        }


        NumberFormat formatter     = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String formatUsersCaptial = formatter.format(doubleUsersCaptial);
        String formatUsersConvertedCapital  = formatter.format(usersConvertedCapital);


        System.out.println(formatUsersCaptial+"US Dollars = "
                          +formatUsersConvertedCapital+" "+pesoOrYen);
        System.out.println("Would you like to run the Program Again?(enter 'yes' or 'no')");
        String runProgramAgain = readKeyboard.nextLine();


        if (runProgramAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            userInputToRunProgramAgain = true;
        }
        else if (runProgramAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            System.out.println("Goood Bye");
            System.exit(0);    
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println ("You entered something other than 'yes' or 'no'\n"
                               +"Good Bye");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }while (userInputToRunProgramAgain==true);
}
```

}

Comment: Any particular reason why you're trying to rewrite this loop in a different way?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html start from here

Comment: @Herman - do you know the difference between a `while` loop and a `do/while` loop?

Comment: It is for my Java class and my profesor asks to use a while loop instead of a do-while.

Comment: Your while condition looks correct. Make sure to "notPesoOrYen==true" before that

Comment: Michael gave you the answer below. The body of a `while` loop executes 0 or more times. The body of a `do/while` executes 1 or more times. That is, the `do/while` body is guaranteed to execute at least once. The question for you to think about: why does your instructor want you to execute the body 0 or more times?

Comment: where did you define this notPesoOrYen variable?

Answer (score 1):

`while` and `do... while` are almost the same, `do... while` simply performs an iteration before evaluating for the first time the exit condition, whereas `while` evaluates it even for the first iteration (so eventually the body of a `while` loop can never be reacher whereas a `do... while` body will always be executed at least once).

Your code snippet is not complete but I guess you didn't initialized `notPesoOrYen` to `true` before the loop and that's why it is not working. Finally, don't write `while(notPesoOrYen==true && numAttempts < 3)` but `while(notPesoOrYen && numAttempts < 3)`, the `== true` comparison is unnecessary.

Comment: I tried this and it would not let the user enter another currency type after runing the program once

Comment: Well the only difference between `while` and `do while` is the first iteration, so if at the beginning the conitnuation condition is true (which is your case), they are strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your boolean variable outside while loop:

```
int numAttempts = 0;
boolean notPesoOrYen=true;
while (notPesoOrYen && numAttempts < 3) {
    System.out.println("Do you want to convert to Peso or Yen?");
    pesoOrYen = readKeyboard.nextLine();

    if (pesoOrYen.equalsIgnoreCase("Peso") || pesoOrYen.equalsIgnoreCase("Yen")) {
        notPesoOrYen = false;
    } else if (numAttempts < 2) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, but '" + pesoOrYen + "' is not a valid currency type. Try again:");
        notPesoOrYen = true; 
    }
    ++numAttempts;
};
```